# Trouble importing scala made jar on java projects

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, intellij-idea, jar

I'm creating a KNIME node whose core is an Scala library that I made. That library was exported as a .jar file via IntelliJ Idea's artifact generation and build (following the default steps and selecting "From modules with dependencies"). In order to use it in the node project, which is an Eclipse project, I go to that project's buildpath and add the Scala library via "Add External Jars...".
This were the steps that I used some time ago when the Scala project was finished and I played around with how could that be used in a Java project. In that test, the library was imported perfectly and I could use the classes.
However, I was having some troubles to be able to include the Scala code, so I made a very simple project using the NumberFormatter node example project for KNIME and a new Scala project via IntelliJ to test. That project has only one package, with one class (object) with one function, which formats the given number. Created a .jar from the project following the same above steps and then included it to the Java KNIME node project the same way. Package is detected correctly and I can use autocompletion to reach the scala object and call its function. However, when I launch KNIME from eclipse, the node will not excecute, raising the excepcion at eclipse's terminal:

```
Execute failed: apackage/Transformer java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: apackage/Transformer
```

apackage was the name of the test package and Trasnformer the name of the object. The exception was caused by

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: apackage.Transformer cannot be found by org.knime.examples.numberformatter_1.0.0.qualifier
```

Thinking that it could be an issue with KNIME, I created a raw java project with a Test class and included the tested Scala library to it, the result is that the package can be seen at import and autocompletion works in it (I can even autocomplete the objects name in the main method) but an error message on the import sentence is shown:

```
The package apackage is not accessible
```

and if I autocomplete the class name, it shows:

```
Transformer cannot be resolved
```

I've searched trough Eclipse and IntelliJ docs and seems like I'm following the correct steps but I can't make it work

Edit, here's the output of jar tf Trasnformer.jar (the jar of the Scala project). The rest of the output are the scala standard library classes
[image: Output]

Comment: They could be in the jar wrong. Please post the output of `jar tf thejar.jar` *formatted as code*

Comment: If you have a `module-info.java` file, delete it (if needed you can recreate it later via right-click on project and _Configure_) or [in `module-info.java` add the required `requires ...;` statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System#Properties_of_modules).

Comment: The jar itself is correct (though you should have posted *as text* [as I mentioned}) so, having tried what @howlger mentioned, the next thing to look at is the classpath. How is that being set?

Comment: Seeing your actual code would help ... But I am guessing, you want  to write `Transformer$.MODULE$` rather than just `Transformer` – that's how scala singletons are represented in java.

Comment: @howlger that file is at the eclipse or intellij project?

Comment: As for @Dima thats how intellij generates the jar, how do I change it, it should compile to java bins in the end

Comment: The `module-info.java` file is not a IDE specific, but a Java thing and must be in the default package. Having a `module-info.java` file enables the [Java Platform Module System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System).